# How to actually start a GKTurnBasedMatch so that I can send an exchange?

Tags: ios, game-center, gkturnbasedmatch

I'm trying to send an exchange to another player in a GKTurnBasedMatch. When I send it, my completion handler gets a big error message, with these descriptions:

```
The requested operation could not be completed because the session is in an invalid state.
Game is not active, session state is Matching
```

I want the match to start when there are just two players, but to allow a total of 16 players. So naturally I'm setting `maxPlayers = 16` and `minPlayers = 2`. I'd thought that would automatically start the match once two players were seated, but it's not so.

I've tried to do this once the match has two players, :

```
    if match.participants?.count == 2 {
      match.status = GKTurnBasedMatchStatus.open
    }
```

But then I'm told that `status` is read-only. I can't manually set it.

Now, with a regular `GKMatch`, I officially start the match by calling:

```
GKMatchmaker.shared().finishMatchmaking(for: match)
```

But there doesn't seem to be a similar thingy for `GKTurnBasedMatch`.

How do I actually get the match started, so I can send an exchange between the two players?

Answer (score 1):

Man, the documentation on `GKTurnBasedMatch` is *sparse.*

Here's the thing: you don't actually start a `GKTurnBasedMatch` explicitly. You only *end* it explicilty.

During gameplay, you just pass the turn from one active player to another active player. The game technically starts as soon as the first player is seated.

The problem I was having is that I had passed the turn when there was no other active player. So I accidentally told Game Center to assign the turn to an empty seat. So when the error message told me

```
Game is not active, session state is Matching
```

It meant that the *current seat was empty* and still looking for a player to fill it. The game apparently goes out of active status any time the current player's status is `Matching` (which denotes an empty seat).

Why on earth this would affect sending exchanges, whose whole purpose is to enable communication between *any* players, *no matter who the current player is,* is beyond me. But there you go.

The solution: make sure that the current turn is held by an actual person, and is not an empty seat. Then you can send exchanges. Otherwise you can't.